# Recording or merging sounds onclick of buttons (as in piano)

Tags: java, android, merge, recording

I have an urgent requirement of capturing the audio stream on 
click of buttons. 
        eg: I play different sounds on click of buttons like in piano. 
              Now i want to capture these sounds played in a single file. 
        The possible ways I tried are -

1)  I merged the sound files played into a single file. 
      (in this case: the merged file has written data of all sound 
files, however it plays 
        only the first sound file- not the other appended sound 
files.)

2)  I then tried merging files using javax.sound, but unfortunately 
android doesn't support 
     this package.

Thinking that merging files would not help-

3)   I thought of recording the sounds played on click of buttons 
using 
      MediaRecorder, AudioRecord even the native audio libraries .... 
      but these methods use Mic as an AudioSource for recording the audio stream 
inducing noise (surrounding sound) which is 
      obviously not as expected.

If anyone has solution or can suggest of resources to solve this 
problem, it would be of great help. 
Thanks in advance :)